# How to add dependency to maven and not to execute it?

Tags: java, maven, entity, frontend, backend

Hi I am developing a web page which will be placed in two different servers - back end and front end.

Back end project has single entities module and multiple modules with beans and remotes.

Entities and remote files are needed in front end. So I just want to give these classes to front end.

I've added dependency to entities module in front end. BUT when I launch front end it executes entities module and makes you able to connect to DB in front end(which is back ends job).

I can solve it by exporting entities folder to jar and adding it to front end, but you will have to do it every time you change something in entities. So I am looking for a better solution - like maven dependency.

I am adding entities dependency this way:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>back-end</groupId>
        <artifactId>back-end-entities</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Make a separate artifact that only contains the entity classes. Use this new artifact by both backend and frontend.

Comment: Front end module finds entity classes while writing code. BUT when i run front end server, I open login page and it shows error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Users". I checked that entities jar is deployed.